# HTTP to HTTPS Redirection Error on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to move my wordpress blog to https, however I tried many things but all of them give me a redirect loop error.

This is my current htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
#The following line is enough for .js and .css
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css   application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom_xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/x-httpd-fastphp text/html

#The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

And i added this to wp-config.php:

```
/* SSL Settings */
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

/* Turn HTTPS 'on' if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO matches 'https' */
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

This are the different variants I tried to redirect to https:

Variant 1:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Variant 2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Variant 3

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

All of them give me a redirect loop, any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you update the Site/Home URL in your `wp_options` table?

Comment: @APAD1 Yes, I did

Comment: First you should check if the ssl is properly installed and propagates. And true for @Daniel James, you should not edit .htaccess for applying ssl. Can you provide your site link? For further testing.

Comment: Thanks @Sakuto, I'm still  pretty noob on here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed it with Really Simple SSL plugin for wordpress, If anyone is having this problem I recommend you try it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use a plugin nor touch the `.htaccess` of your WordPress installation to get it to work on HTTPS. Change the **Site** and **WordPress URLs** in the admin area within ***Settings*** > ***General***.

Here is a useful guide on [how to change the site URLs](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/).

You can also just [force it within the admin area](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) only by putting the following in your `config.php` file (in the WordPress root), although having it everywhere is best.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Generally though, I'd avoid using a plugin for something like this which can be done natively and easily too.